# How to make a div fade in after a specific height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a fixed div appear after the user scrolls 100px down on a page, and disappears again when the scroll past that 100px to the top.

I would like to use a opacity fade transition of 0.5s when the div appears to make a nice transition.

Have been trying to do this but can only seem to get it to appear as soon as the user scrolls using this code:

Would love to hear from someone who has the solution.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please provide more context, and show some of your own research first

Comment: I assume that Javascript would be used for this but don't know much more. Someone must know what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start http://jsfiddle.net/ZtGK6/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop()>100){
         $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
      }else{
         $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
      }

});
```

Comment: Hey the only problem is it fades in on page load. Is there any way to modify code so that it doesnt appear on load?

Comment: just add `$("#theDiv").hide()` before the scroll event.

Comment: Nothing changes if you put it above the function . . @TheSuperTramp

Comment: Yeah that seems to work but everytime I scroll it disappers then appears again. Possibly because its looping the hide line? @TheSuperTramp Close though! nearly there just need to figure out how ???

Answer (score 1):

A good way to make it hide on page load is to give the surrounding div CSS class a `display: none;` property. That way it will display hidden when the page initially loads, and not fade out quickly upon page load. Then, your JavaScript will load it after you scroll down the determined # of pixels. This will behave cleanly and is super easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="theDiv">Now I'm visible</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 200%;
}

#theDiv{
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
    display: none;
    background-color:#FFF000;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop()>100){
         $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
      }else{
         $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
      }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/ZtGK6/3/

Comment: Good thinking! Tried setting the div to display:none but it still appears the re-appears when the page is loaded??? @waitinforatrain

Comment: What do you mean by "re-appears"?

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {

    var theDiv = $('#myDiv'),
        scrollPos = $('body').scrollTop();

    if ( scrollPos > 100 ) {

        theDiv.fadeIn(500); // 500 milliseconds

    } else {

        theDiv.fadeOut(500);

    }

});
```

I haven't been able to test this and you may have to put the `if` statement in a scroll event so the `scrollPos` var updates as you scroll.